# Node.js- Splitting up File Path with string.split()... Top Level File Gets Excluded

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have these routines that split up the file path. The issue that I am having is with `/home/one/github/load-balancer-service/app/js/app.coffee`. It seems to exclude the `app.coffee` and just leaves `/js/` for `srcFile`

Not sure why. Any ideas? For files in sub directories underneath `js/foo/file.coffee` it's not a issue.

```
  srcPath = "app";
  console.log(streamObject.history[0]);
  var projectDir = streamObject.history[0].split(srcPath)[0];
  console.log(projectDir);
  var srcFile = streamObject.history[0].split(srcPath)[1];
  console.log(srcFile);
```

---

output:

```
/home/one/github/load-balancer-service/app/js/app.coffee
/home/one/github/load-balancer-service/
/js/
```

Comment: AFAIK when splitting, the character you split on doesn't get included.

Comment: Oh, I see...it splits on `app.coffee` also. Thanks!

Comment: Should setting the limit fix this...such as `streamObject.history[0].split(srcPath, 2)`? Not having success on that.

Comment: Wish I could use `path.parse` but I am not able to upgrade `node` shell to 0.12.0.